Create GWC for layer group or single Layers
I have a geoserver instance (v2.25.3) which has several layers from a PostGIS store. All those layers are merged as one Group Layer, which will be used by my application.
I now want to use cache to speed up display. Should I create a GWC for each individual layer or a GWC for the group?

You need to cache any layer that your clients request. This happens by default so you probably don't need to do anything

Thanks Ian. Understood. I just realized that the problem was that I was not sending TILED WMS requests. But since the layers are pretty big, I'm seeding the first zoom levels (0-7)
